# Modify input before executing Python class definition

Tags: python, class

I am still learning how Python classes work. Here is my sample code:

```
class StringPopped(str):
    def __init__(self, input):
        super().__init__()
        self.output = input[:-1]

str1 = StringPopped('Alice')
```

Then the output for `>>> str1` is `Alice` and `str1.output` is `Alic`. How do I make `str1` have the same result as `str1.output`?

I tried `__repr__` but that only changes what is displayed and not what the value of `str1` actually is. Is there a way to make a statement like `self = self.output`?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a case for a class at all. This should be a function, `def f(string): return string[:-1]`.

Comment: If you want to learn about how Python classes work, inheriting from builtin types is not going to be a fun way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable.  I guess you'll have to approach this with [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), not `__init__`:

```
>>> class StringPopped(str):
...     def __new__(cls, val):
...         return super().__new__(cls, val[:-1])
...     
>>> s = StringPopped('Alice')
>>> s
'Alic'
>>> type(s)
__main__.StringPopped
```